# How can I add space between features in d3 geo projections

Tags: d3.js, geospatial

I have a simple d3 geojson projection [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sAGmO03KV9B4QmgvNHk7). I am using the following for my scaling...

```
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .translate([$scope.width / 2, $scope.height / 2]);
```

Is there a way to add a margin between the state "features" in this projection. So say I want 10px between the borders of every state.

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590), it uses [topojson.mesh](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference#mesh) to create a nice border about US states (set to 1.5px in the CSS).

Comment: Something like a [*Non-Contiguous Cartogram*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4055908)?

Comment: Are you sure it is separating them and not just drawing the border over the previous "state path". I want them physically separable so that if that margin increases to some crazy number they are still separated and not just white.

Comment: @altocumulus thanks I will look at that one